# ASP.NET WebForm : Invalid JSON primitive on Page Change

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am working on `ASP.NET WebForm` app.

I have a page which calls `Handler` through `AJAX` call.
Data are loaded into `telerik` radgrid and html chart for presentation.

I am copying those html elements to other div. It is fine and showing data correctly.

Issue occurs only when I try to redirect to another page. App uses common master page for navigation.

I have tried updating IDs for each html elements. App uses code behind for navigation page which has not been hitted.

```
var ID = 1;
data.forEach(function (item) {
    var tableView = $find("<%=rgVol.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    tableView.set_dataSource(item.volumeOfPurchReqs);
    tableView.dataBind();

    var chart = $find("<%=rhcBar.ClientID %>");
    // Set the new datasource to the RadHtmlChart
    chart.set_dataSource(item.volumeOfPurchReqs);

    // Repaint the RadHtmlChart to apply the changes
    chart.repaint();

    const elementsInsideMyDiv = getElementsInsideDiv('chart-containers');
    //changing common ID to UniqueID
    divElement += addUniqueIDToHTML(elementsInsideMyDiv, ID);
    ID++;
});
//setting html elements to div 
setHTMLToDiv('ChartList', divElement);
```

Issue is only produced when above code is executed if not then app does not encounter any issue.

Issue encountered:
[image: Issue encountered]

**Rad Components**

```
     <div id="chart-containers" style="display: none">
                    <div class="chart-containers">
                        <div class="chart-container no-bg ">
                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgVol" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" Width="650px" PageSize="10" CssClass="RadGridCustomClass">
                                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="RadGriheader, Myheader" />
                                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Field1" TableLayout="Auto" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" ShowFooter="true">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field1" UniqueName="Field1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                            HeaderText="Field1">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field2" UniqueName="Field2" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                            HeaderText="Field2">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field3" UniqueName="Field3" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                            HeaderText="Field3">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                            HeaderText="Percent" UniqueName="Percent" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="Percent">
                                            <ClientItemTemplate>
                                      #=formatPercent(Percent)#
                                            </ClientItemTemplate>
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    </Columns>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" ShowPagerText="false" Mode="NumericPages" />
                                <ClientSettings>
                                    <ClientEvents OnRowDataBound="rgVol_OnRowDataBound" />
                                </ClientSettings>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chart-container no-bg size-medium">
                            <telerik:RadHtmlChart Transitions="false" runat="server" ID="rhcBar" Width="500px" Height="500px">
                                <PlotArea>
                                    <Series>
                                        <telerik:BarSeries Name="Field3" DataFieldY="Field3">
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#2885BA"></FillStyle>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{0}"></TooltipsAppearance>
                                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                                            </LabelsAppearance>
                                        </telerik:BarSeries>
                                    </Series>
                                    <XAxis DataLabelsField="Field1">
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false"></MinorGridLines>
                                        <MajorGridLines Visible="false"></MajorGridLines>
                                    </XAxis>
                                    <YAxis>
                                        <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0}"></LabelsAppearance>
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false"></MinorGridLines>
                                    </YAxis>
                                </PlotArea>
                                <Legend>
                                    <Appearance Visible="false"></Appearance>
                                </Legend>
                            </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where in the code above is the exception generated? Start from the bottom and comment out lines until you find it. Also, this exception is frequently the result of incorrect application of ajax to rad components. Please share you ajax markup/declaration.

Comment: Issue occurs while setting html elements to div. Rad component has no issue if it created for single instance but i am using same component to create multiple copy. So, issue occurs. You can check rad components, I have updated Rad Components also.